# Angular problems chaining $resource promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I was trying to chain some promises for this service I have but the $stateprovider resolves without waiting for $q. This results in my controller getting back the result object with just the empty array, and the object gets filled later on. Where is my promise chain going wrong?

#### My $stateprovider:

```
    .state('somestate', {
        resolve: {
            neededvalue: function(anotherservice) {
                return anotherservice.getData(); //this one works pretty well , but doesn't use any chaining
            },
            finalvalue: function(myService, neededvalue) {
                return myService.startChain(neededvalue);
            }
        }
    }
```

#### My Service:

```
    app.factory("myService",
            ['$resource', '$q',
        function ($resource, $q) {

            var firstApi = $resource("api/somewhere/first", {}, { "getData": { method: "POST" } });
            var secondApi = $resource("api/somewhere/second", {}, { "getData": { method: "POST" } });

            var result = {
                array: []
            };

            var myService = {
                startChain: startChain
            };

            return myService;

            function startChain(someNeededValues) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                firstApi
                    .getData(someNeededValues.values).$promise
                    .then(function (data) {
                        result.value = data.value;
                    })
                    .then(recurringAction)
                    .then(deferred.resolve(result));

                return deferred.promise;
            }

            function recurringAction() {
                return secondApi.getData(result.value, function (data) {
                    angular.copy(data.array, result.array);   
                }).$promise;
            }

        }]);
```

Answer (score 3):

not sure if your script worked the way you intended to when you passed `deferred.resolve(result)` as a callback to promise...

so just change

```
                .then(deferred.resolve(result));
```

to

```
                .then(function(){
                    deferred.resolve(result)
                });
```

Comment: I'm expecting the `result` object to be returned as `finalvalue` in the state provider, thus I have to resolve the deferrer object as I returned that promise there. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes, but there's a major difference between providing `deferred.resolve` and `deferred.resolve(value)` - the former is being passed to execute later on in the chain, while the latter is being executed right away

Comment: is the solution provided the one you were after? :)

Comment: this was just a syntax error after all, but I'm not sure about your method here. My solution does work as I intended, this is $q as provided in the angularJS library, are you thinking about the $Q or the Jquery one?

Comment: I think I understand what you are getting at, problem is I'm not returning the values from the second action, I'm returning a custom object made up from values of both calls. Wouldn't this solution just return the `data.array` instead of the `result` object that has `result.array` AND `result.value`. Your way probably works in most scenarios where you only need to return from the second API.

Comment: ah! i totally missed that bit - you're right. but still - in that case, just pass the value to the other promise and return that promise's result WITH that value :-)

Comment: That would work, but in my case I'm using the recurringAction in more situations so I do not want to pass in the result there.

But you essentially pointed at my error, I should supply the `.then` with a callback but I didn't. If you change your answer to point that out along with how your solution would work and in my case use `function(){deferred.resolve(result);})` I would award you with correct answer.

Do you know the deferred was resolved in my first case scenario, does js resolve the method when it's passed in as parameter at interpretation.

Comment: i'm not fishing for points here, so no need for that - as long as I helped you out, I'm happy :-)

Comment: It would mostly be helpful to the next guy that comes along :)

Answer (score 1):

Its an expected behavior of `ng-resource` promise

From [**Angular Doc**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) directly

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick
>   since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then
>   rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering,
>   once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated
>   with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the
>   new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a
>   callback function for the action methods.

Comment: But I'm using the `$promise` object that comes with the `$resource` return, notice I never return the values from the `$resource` object.

Comment: which is what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: @IngóVals but return `$promise` doesn't mean it will behave differently

Comment: I can ensure it does, the `$promise.then` ensures the `$resource` has finished and I resolve the `$q` at that time. Notice I'm not returning the object from the `$resource` call.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this was actually a stupid mistake on my behalf.

I needed to wrap the `deferred.resolve` inside of a function.

```
    function startChain(someNeededValues) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        firstApi
            .getData(someNeededValues.values).$promise
            .then(function (data) {
                result.value = data.value;
            })
            .then(recurringAction)
            .then(function () {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Seems like $defer auto resolves or something if there is no .resolve method available.

Comment: no need to wrap it into a function - just pass `deferred.resolve` as an argument for `then()` like: `then(deferred.resolve)`

Comment: @tomasz-stryjewski NOT TRUE.  If you call a method of an object indirectly like that, either by assigning it to a var or by passing it as an argument (same thing really) then it **loses its `this` reference**, because `this` refers to the object in the dot-notation.

Comment: I didn't mean that as a general rule, but AFAIK in **this scenario** it works just fine, as `this` reference is not used - or am I missing something?

Comment: If it does then it's extreme luck that `this` within the `promise.then` happens to point to the/a right thing, or isn't used as you say - and who's to say it will always be the case.  My point was that this is the kind of easy mistake that we should be discouraging at every opportunity.  The ambiguity is that `.then(recurringAction)` works fine, because it has no instance context, so from there it's easy to slip into `.then(something.recurringAction)`.

Comment: I wouldn't call that *extreme luck* - you can see that it works just fine on this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/R8a1AXe0V2OdLbevLAoU?p=preview

and this being *"easy mistake that we should discourage at every opportunity"* - I don't agree here - getting a deeper understanding of how and why things work is a real benefit.

could you please edit the *NOT TRUE* statement, as it is... well... *TRUE*?

Comment: @tomaszstryjewski Are you certain that this works. Notice I need the resolve to return the `result` object. In your suggestion how does the resolve know what the return should be?

Comment: if your previous callback for `then` statement returned the `result`, the promise would resolve with that value